# why does cmake compiles everything after git commit

Tags: git, compilation, cmake

Lets say I have a code compiling at some time with cmake 2.8 on linux.

I change a file "my_changed_file", run cmake, and only this one file is built. So far so good.

Now i want to commit this:

```
git add my_changed_file
git commit
```

If I run cmake again, i'd expect nothing happens. But all my files are recompiled, despite I didn't touched anything! The timestamp appears to be untouched when I do ls -l.

I do have these lines:

```
execute_process(
  COMMAND git describe --abbrev=8 --dirty --always --tags
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_CODE_VERSION
  OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)
add_definitions("-DCODE_VERSION=${GIT_CODE_VERSION}")
```

But it only affect the file main.cpp

What is happening ?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CMake doesn't track, which source file can be affected by particular compile definition. When compile definitions *changes*, CMake assumes that **all sources should be rebuilt**.

Better approach is to use *configured header file*. So, when content of this file is changed, only those sources will be recompiled which includes this file(directly or indirectly):

**version.h.in**:

```
#define CODE_VERSION @GIT_CODE_VERSION@
```

**main.cpp**:

```
#include "version.h"
...
```

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
# Calculate value of variable GIT_CODE_VERSION
...
configure_file("version.h.in" "version.h")
```

Nice thing with `configure_file` is that it doesn't update resulted file's timestamp if its *content* wouldn't be changed. So, if you rerun `cmake` without `git commit`, nothing will be recompiled on next build. Only rerunning `cmake` after `git commit` will force `main.cpp` file(and only it) to be recompiled on next build.

---

Another way is to use [COMPILE_DEFINITIONS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_sf/COMPILE_DEFINITIONS.html) property on specific source files instead of target-wide one (which is affected by `add_definition()` call):

```
set_property(SOURCE main.cpp APPEND
    PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "-DCODE_VERSION=${GIT_CODE_VERSION}")
```

Changing this property via `cmake` call will be detected by build system, so next build will recompile `main.cpp` and only it.

Unfortunately, this approach doesn't work as expected in case of makefile generators: even if compile definitions are changed for specific source, all sources (for same target) will be rebuilt. This is [known limitation](http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake-developers/2012-October/005411.html).

Comment: hi. I tried adding or replacing my add_definition with the set_property, but it doesn't seem to do much. Is there something different to do ? SHould it be placed somewhere ? If i don't specify COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_$CONFIG, then it applies to every configuration, right ? Thanks

Comment: I found that per-source COMPILE_DEFINITIONS doesn't work as expected with makefile generator(which you uses). But there is better approach which uses configure header file. I have updated my answer for that case.

Comment: To reduce what gets rebuilt even further, instead of regenerating a header every time the git commit details change, put the `@GIT_CODE_VERSION@` in an implementation file (e.g. `version.cpp.in`) inside a trivial function and copy that file with `configure_file`. The header then contains just the function prototype and never changes. The result will be just that one implementation file needs to be rebuilt, not every file that includes `version.h`.

Comment: @CraigScott: Nice hint. Unless version string is needed only as a macro(e.g., for construct static constant strings), configuring additional source file instead of header one can reduce compile time significantly.