# CMake: trigger regeneration of Makefiles when environment variable changes

Tags: makefile, cmake

I am using Linux, CMake, and Conda, which is a package manager that edits `$PATH` as a way to switch between "environments."  This means when I run a special command in Conda, `$PATH` points to a different compiler.  `$CONDA_PREFIX` is also changed.

By default, CMake is not sensitive to these changes.  I would like it to be.  Specifically, I want CMake to automatically regenerate all Makefiles when a different GCC is found in `$PATH`, or alternatively when `$CONDA_PREFIX` has changed since the last explicit `cmake` invocation.  This regeneration would be similar to what CMake does when you edit the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file - the next time you run `make` it regenerates everything.

How can I do this in a simple way using CMake?

Comment: Natural approach seems to create new build tree for every additional "environment".

Comment: @Tsyvarev: I understand what you mean but that doesn't solve the problem--if a user accidentally is in the wrong (mismatched) Conda environment vs CMake build tree, the build may be defective.  I am trying to make sure builds are never mismatched.

Comment: You may add target (via `add_custom_target`), which will check that  build tree corresponds to current environment. For mismatched builds target could simply fails with appropriate message. Forcing CMake to rerun (see, e.g., [that mail](http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake/2010-November/040777.html)) could be useful if you need *partial* reconfiguration. But as compiler is changed, you probably need to discard all compiler-related caches, which is actually a clean configuration (`cmake` call on clean build directory).

Comment: Looks like a CMake's misfeature. It's supposed to be a high-level build tool, but leaves it to you to deal with such a trivial changes as compiler commands explicitly depending on environment, or the compiler itself.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up not needing a workaround code today, but here's an idea. It's not general - it requires you to explicitly specify the variables your build depends on.

- Create a CMake wrapper script that receives the names of environment variables that affect my specific build.
- `echo` them all in `VARIABLE=value` format into a `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/buildvars.environment` file. Only do it if the file doesn't exist or if its content is different.
- When calling `cmake`, add `cmake -DCMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS=<build_direcotry>/buildvars.environment` to trigger reconfiguration if the file is newer than build configuration.

References:

- [CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR.html)
- [CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS.html)
- may also use [copy_if_different](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/manual/cmake.1.html?highlight=copy_if_different) instead of checking the file contents.

Related question: [How to trigger a CMake reconfigure when the output of a command changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38220304/how-to-trigger-a-cmake-reconfigure-when-the-output-of-a-command-changes)

Answer (score 0):

In short, the generated build directory should no more depend on environment.

> if a user accidentally is in the wrong (mismatched) Conda environment vs CMake build tree, the build may be defective.

If you've used [find_program()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/find_program) command to determine paths to all tools you are using then this would never happen. Using full path for every tool and having a build dir for each environment setup is the preffered way to handle this problem.

Comment: CMake totally leaves the build environment management to the user, but dictates how we should do it ("thou shan't depend on environment variables"). Probably that downvote could be an upvote if you prepend the answer with "CMake's (bad) idea of environment management is..."